# Could not find method named Get(Login) or Any(Login) on Service

Tags: c#, servicestack

I get the following error when trying to send an HTTP POST request to my login endpoint:

"Could not find method named Get(Login) or Any(Login) on Service LoginService"

The Login class has three properties namely username, password, and rememberMe. 
This is how I send the request:

```
 var client = new JsonServiceClient(ApiHost());
 var loginResponse = client.Post(new Login
 {
     Username = Username,
     Password = Password,
     RememberMe = true
 });
```

I believe I am sending a POST request but why does it complain about not having a GET method implemented?

Comment: What does your `Login` DTO look like? please also provide the Server implementation method signature. Also can you post the raw HTTP Request/Response headers using something like Fiddler so we can tell what's really going on?

Comment: I added https to the ApiHost url and it works fine now.